# Python UTC offset value

Tags: python, python-2.7, utc

I'm trying to convert this 20130607T064835-0700 into unix time representation. Unfortunately I can't do it for some reason. I've managed to create some code but it doesn't work.

```
time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime('20130607T064835-0700', '%Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z').strftime("%s"))
```

It looks like datetime representation of %z in Python is not working well.

```
>>> print time.strftime('%z')
Central European Daylight Time
>>> print time.strftime('%Z')
Central European Daylight Time
```

I think %z should return offset like it's said in documentation:

```
%z  UTC offset in the form +HHMM or -HHMM (empty string if the the object is naive).
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What OS? I believe the time functions all use the underlying C libraries on your system; on my system I get `-0400` and `EDT` for your examples.

Comment: Windows... Yup you're right this is system issue, I've tried to do it on Linux and it works well. How can I convert this on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

To get the unix time of your timestamp under windows you can do the following (tested on python 2.7):

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

t = parse('20130607T064835-0700')
e = datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=pytz.utc)
d = t - e

unixtime = d.total_seconds()
```